# Returning address using function pointer

Tags: c++

Hi All I have written a code as shown below

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
int main()
{
    int *fun();
    int *p;
    p = fun();
    cout << "address contained in p " << p << endl;
    cout << "value contained  in p " << *p << endl;





    cin.get();

}
int *fun()
{
    int a = 20;
    return (&a);
}
```

In the output i get

address contained in p  00f3fc48

value contained in p 26238874

why is output different from what i expected (*p=20 as i am returning address of a from function pointer)??

I am writing this code in visual studio.

Does compiler matters in this case?

Comment: You are returning the address of a local variable declared only inside that function. That variable is destroyed once the function returns so this is not a good idea.

Comment: The *life-time* of all non-static local variables ends when the scope they were defined in end. For the variable `a` inside the function `fun`, its life-time ends when the function ends.

Comment: Thanks @Someprogrammerdude .Got the point.